# ¿Cómo hacer un insert desde una app creada en Phonegap?

Tags: mysql, json, phonegap

¿Cómo se hace una insert utilizando Phonegap, JSON y MySQL? Consigo consultar los datos de la base de datos, pero me falta la otra parte no menos importante: INSERTAR datos desde la app.

Pongo el ejemplo de la consulta de datos que funciona bien:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var dato1="";
    var dato2="";
    var dato3="";

    function traer() {
        $.getJSON('http://www.retegi.eus/demostracion/traer.php',

            function(data){
                dato1=data[0].Id;
                dato2=data[0].Nombre;
                dato3=data[0].Apellido;

                         }
              );
    }
    function mostrar() {
        $("#dato-1").text(dato1);
        $("#dato-2").text(dato2);
        $("#dato-3").text(dato3);
    }


</script>
```

Y por otro lado el archivo que se ejecuta en la base de datos:

```
<?php 
    $host = "";
    $usuario = "";
    $pass = "";
    $bd = "";

    $servidor = mysql_connect($host, $usuario, $pass);

    mysql_set_charset("utf8", $servidor);
    $conexion = mysql_select_db($bd, $servidor);

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM datos";
    $sql = mysql_query($consulta);

    $datos= array();

    while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
        $datos[] = array('Id' => $obj->Id,
                          'Nombre' => $obj->Nombre,
                          'Apellido' => $obj->Apellido,
            );
    }

    echo '' . json_encode($datos) . '';
    mysql_close($servidor);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```

Comment: ¿Con qué dificultades te estás encontrando? Aparte, como comentario: no deberías usar las funciones `mysql_*` se consideran obsoletas y se eliminaron a partir de PHP 7.

Comment: La dificultad que encuentro es que normalmente hago insert desde web con php, pero al no poder ejecutar php en una app porque es del lado servidor, no se cómo se hace para enviar valores de un formulario a la base de datos mediante JSON. xD Saludos.

Comment: Es bastante parecido al código que ya tienes para la búsqueda. Si has hecho un insert desde web llamando al PHP con AJAX, es básicamente lo mismo.